# Prolog: how can i count number in prolog?

Tags: prolog

if the goal can (5,3) the out put could be 5,4,3 this my code found big error

```
 predicates
     count(integer, integer)
 clauses 
     count(X, Y) :- X > Y, write(3), !.
     count(X < Y) :- X > Y, write(X), nl, X1 = X-1, count(X1, Y).
```

Comment: What was the error, specifically?

Comment: Please explain what this predicate is supposed to do in general, not just a specific example with no context.

Comment: I don't know what the condition to print from 5 to 3 or from -3 to 0  etc.

Comment: Arithmetic assignment is done with `is`, not `=`. So for example, `X1 is X + 1`. Why does the `X > Y` case just write `3`?

Answer (score 2):

```
count(X,X):-write(X),nl.
count(X,Y):-X<Y,write(X),nl,X1 is X+1,count(X1,Y).
```

Comment: You can't do arithmetic assignment with `=`. You need to use `is`. So the above won't work.